# VM - Create vCPU with multiple threads

Tags: virtualization

I'm looking for a virtualization solution that allows to create vCPUs that have multiple threads e.g (1 Processor / 4 Threads).

It's all about running an older software that is licensed to CPU cores but not threads so I'm trying to gain some performance boost. Unfortunately it's not possibile to buy any more licences for cores as the product isn't sold anymore.

The host can be either Windows or Linux, the guest is Debian. Physical hardware resources on the server aren't a problem.

This configuration should appear that way inside the guest OS.

So far i've tried major hyper visors (hyper-v, qemu, vmware, virtualbox) and none gives the possibility to configure virtual processors at this level of detail. I've also searched accross google and haven't found anything similiar, but maybe I've overlooked some advanced configuration especially in KVM.

The licensing or cost of the virtualization solution is not important.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with virt-manager tool (Libvirt+Qemu)

Example:
[image]

The qemu argument is: `-smp 1,maxcpus=4,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=4`

Enjoy!
Emeric